# AFP or SMB file links in a url

Tags: url, smb, afp

Is it possible to create a url in the form of afp://server/share/someDirectory/someFile.ext to when you open it on a mac in safari, or through mail, it navigates to that folder or file?

I've played with the file://localhost/share/someDirectory/someFile.ext but this often times will not be universal across a group of machines.  Mac adds "-1" to shares with duplicate names, and if you mount it manually with a different mount point than the share name this will also not work.

My plan was to use links with the smb:// or afp:// url, which includes the mount address and location of the file.  However, when I do this, Mac will find the file, but it will mount that share at a subdirectory such as someDirectory, compared to the usual mount point of share.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be discussed also on https://superuser.com/questions/105361/what-is-the-mac-equivalent-of-the-file-url

IMHO there is no way to get those links on a mac

There is also no hint to that in the Apple KB: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568

With kind regards,
~Marcel

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Just select the containing folder in Finder and press control+option+command+C. MacOS then creates the link you want, to paste where you please.